# Haskell elem function's Big O runtime

Tags: haskell, big-o

What is the Big O runtime of Haskell's [elem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#elem) function?

Comment: For a list *O(n)* equality checks, for another foldable, it depends on the foldable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Since the only thing available is `Eq`, how could it be anything but comparing every element?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: well "walking" over a foldable does not per se happens in constant time. It is for example possible that it requires *O(log n)* time to access the next element.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, so you mean to say that it could be _worse_ than O(n)? Then yes, good point.

Comment: In fairness it would be a pretty unusual container that had worse than O(1) amortized time to access each element. Obviously such can be constructed, but are any popular ones in common use?

Answer (score -2):

It is O(n) since it has to check all of the items.